# Why is the non-symmetric function, the Jacobian used in changes of variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian, change-of-variable

For example, if we take the polar coordinates $x(r, \theta) = r\cos \theta$ and $y(r, \theta) = r \sin \theta$ the Jacobian is

$$\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(r,\theta)} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}-\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}{\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}} = r\cos^2(x) + r\sin^2(x) = r$$

Hence $dxdy = r\space drd\theta$ This is not symmetric with respect to the variables like one would expect though. Expressing $x$ and $y$ as functions of $r$ and $\theta$ in that order is an arbitrary convention. We could just as easily write $x(\theta,r) = r\cos\theta$ and $y(\theta, r) = r\sin\theta$ in which case the Jacobian would be $-r$ and $dx dy$ would transform into $-r\space drd\theta$.

Comment: You might be interested in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3775725/26369) to [Why can't we convert the area element $dA$ to polar by multiplying the polar expressions for $dx$ and $dy$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3769936/26369), which touches upon the idea of the order mattering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change-of-variables formula is with the *absolute value* of the determinant of the Jacobian, not with just the Jacobian itself. So in either case we have
$$ dx dy = | \det J |dr d\theta = r dr d\theta.$$

See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables