# Understanding the Jacobian for polar to cartesian coordinates transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, jacobian

I'm still learning calculus and Jacobian, and I am confused because I don't intuitively understand what Jacobian actually does and how to interpret its result.
For example, I consider the Jacobian for convertion from polar to Cartesian coordinate system.

The conversion from polar to Cartesian coordinates is done like this:
$$
x(r,\theta)=r\cos(\theta) \\
y(r,\theta)=r\sin(\theta)
$$

The Jacobian of the transformation is defined like this:
$$
J =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(\theta) & -r\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Each row of which is transposed gradient of functions $x$ and $y$.

From linear algebra course I learned that a column in a matrix represents new coordinates of i-th basis vector.
But from the Jacobian above I see that at least the first column does not represent the new coordinates of the vector $\hat{i}$ in Cartesian coordinate system after applying the transformation as I expected because it does not depend on coordinate $r$ in polar coordinate system as it should (I think).

**Question 1:**
If the columns do not represent the change in basis vectors in Cartesian coordinate system, then what they do represent?

Also I struggle to interpret the resulting matrix of linear transformation after substituting the coordinates from polar coordinate system.

For example $(r, \theta)=(2,\pi)$.
The coordinates in Cartesian coordinate system should be equal to $(x,y)=(2\cos(\pi),2\sin(\pi))=(-2, 0)$.

$$
J =
\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(\pi) & -2\sin(\pi) \\
\sin(\pi) & 2\cos(\pi) \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Question 2:** How to interpret the Jacobian above? What transformation the matrix does? 
Well, as I expected, the vectors are rotated by 180 degrees (since $\theta=\pi$), but the $\hat{j}$ vector is stretched by 2 instead of vector $\hat{i}$ as I expected.

**Question 3:** How we defined the order of variables $r$ and $\theta$? Why $r$ corresponds to $x$ and not to $y$? What will happen if I swap the variables $r$ and $\theta$ (meaning swapping the order of them in the functions $x$ and $y$, also changing the order of colunms in the Jacobian)?
If I swap the variables $r$ and $\theta$ then the columns of the Jacobian matrix will also swap, swapping the $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ vectors, which changes the result.

Sorry for such a newbie questions.
Hope for your help!

Comment: This is the best linear approximation to the change of coordinates. For a non-linear change of coordinates, the usual linear algebra change of basis stuff doesn’t quite make sense.

Comment: Q1: Don't worry about the rows, focus on the columns instead. Q2: The pictures in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146249/1242) gives you the geometric meaning of the columns, and hence of the whole linear transformation. Q3: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968613/why-is-the-non-symmetric-function-the-jacobian-used-in-changes-of-variables).

Comment: @HansLundmark, thank you very much! This helps a lot