# Oddity in the change of volume due to a change of coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, volume

I was thinking about coordinates change and, using polar coordinates on a 2D plane, i found an incoherence in my equations

$$x=r cos \theta \\ y=r sin \theta$$

from wich
$$dx=cos\theta dr-rsin \theta d\theta \\ dy=sin \theta dr+rcos \theta d \theta$$

then, multiplying $dx$ and $dy$
$$dxdy=cos\theta sin \theta dr^2 + rcos \theta^2 dr d\theta  - rsin \theta^2 d\theta dr- r^2  sin\theta cos\theta d\theta^2$$

while, using the standard procedure with the determinant of the Jacobian we obtain a different result:  $$dxdy=rd\theta dr$$ I'm sure $dxdy=rd\theta dr$ is the correct result but i don't understand what is wrong with the procedure above

Comment: You can't just multiply differentials together like that.  Also, $sen$ is written $\sin$.

Comment: Why not? btw i corrected, now is sin

Comment: because the differentials are not real numbers, so they don't obey the same laws of algebra as real numbers.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3275058/568204) for more details; I'm sure there are tons of more duplicates

Comment: [Another answer I wrote regarding this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3628070/568204)

Comment: Interesting but why many times, like in Taylor expansions, differentials are multiplied the same way real numbers are?

Comment: Taylor expansion deals with real numbers. $f(a+h)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}h^k + R_{n,a}(h)$. THere are no differentials lying around. Anyway, just because sometimes differentials are treated like real numbers in single-variable calculus (those uses should definitely be made more precise), it doesn't mean things always work out (and this polar coordinate example is a very good illustration of this fact).